# MediaCodec sub-second video length

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm using `MediaCodec` to encode an image into a video. It is a requirement that videos can have sub-second length (e.g. 3.5 seconds long).

My thinking in order to achieve this is is to determine the video frame rate like so.

```
int lengthInMillis = 3500;
float seconds = lengthInMillis / 1000f;
int ordinal = (int) seconds; // ordinal == 3
float point = seconds - ordinal;
float numFrames = seconds / point; // numFrames == 7
float fps = seconds / numFrames; // fps = 0.7
this.numFrames = (int) numFrames;
```

Unfortunately when attempting to configure the `MediaCodec` with a `KEY_FRAME_RATE` of less than 1 an `IllegalStateException`. So this method doesn't work. Is it possible to use `MediaCodec` to create a video with a running time that ends at a fraction of a second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of the video, and the frame rate of the video, are not related.

A 3.5-second video with 7 frames is running at 2 fps, not 0.7 fps.  You should be computing "frames per second" as "frames / seconds", not `seconds / numFrames`.

In any event, the frame-rate value is actually [deprecated in API 21](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html):

> Note: On LOLLIPOP, the format to MediaCodecList.findDecoder/EncoderForFormat must not contain a frame rate. Use format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, null) to clear any existing frame rate setting in the format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So since the the KEY_FRAME_RATE is deprecated, how do I encode a video of a predetermined length. I'm attempting to create a video from a user generated still image.

Comment: If you're creating a video from a single still image, you'll need to encode two frames, setting the presentation time stamps 3.5 seconds apart. You could encode the same frame twice, or encode a blank frame as the second frame to have it reset to black when "playback" ends.